# Word VBA "Saveas" without hidden text?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to programmatically saveas from a Microsoft Word .docm without including hidden text?

I'm having users click a button that does a few other things and then opens up a save as dialog to save the .docm file as an .html file, by using this in the Word VB editor:

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Format = wdFormatHTML
    .Show
End With
```

It saves everything that appears on the page but also saves the paragraphs that are currently hidden. (They're also hidden in the Web display of the html page, but the hidden content is still in the .html, marked with `mso-hideall` tags.) I would like to only save the content that is *not* hidden, if possible, so that it's not in the html file at all.

I don't see anything that provides for that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx), but I'm wondering if anyone might know of a way to do this using VB.

I've been working on deleting the hidden text using VBA, but it's tricky because you have to show it first, then select it, then delete it, and which parts are hidden is different each time depending on what the user selects in the Word .docm document.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the complete code I have now:

```
Public strActiveOption As String

Private Sub OptionConcept_Click()
strActiveOption = "OptionConcept"

Bookmarks("ConceptText").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("TaskText").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Bookmarks("RefText").Range.Font.Hidden = True




End Sub

Private Sub OptionTask_Click()
strActiveOption = "OptionTask"
Bookmarks("TaskText").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("ConceptText").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Bookmarks("RefText").Range.Font.Hidden = True


End Sub



Private Sub OptionReference_Click()
strActiveOption = "OptionReference"
Bookmarks("RefText").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("ConceptText").Range.Font.Hidden = True
Bookmarks("TaskText").Range.Font.Hidden = True


End Sub

Private Sub formatSave_Click()
'Concept Content = 3
'Task Steps = 4
'ReferenceData = 5

Select Case strActiveOption
 Case "OptionConcept"
 ActiveDocument.ContentControls(4).Delete
 ActiveDocument.ContentControls(5).Delete
Case "OptionTask"
 ActiveDocument.ContentControls(3).Delete
 ActiveDocument.ContentControls(5).Delete
Case "OptionReference"
 ActiveDocument.ContentControls(3).Delete
 ActiveDocument.ContentControls(4).Delete
Case Else
    MsgBox "Invalid option"
End Select

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Format = wdFormatHTML
    .Show
End With
End Sub
```

What it does: There are three option buttons on the page, and content controls are hidden or unhidden depending on which one the user selects. The code in `Private Sub formatSave_Click()` reads which one is selected and tries to delete the appropriate hidden text.

**Problems:**

Everything in the first subs works perfectly, down to `Private Sub formatSave_Click()`. After that, it seems to not be able to see the hidden contentcontrols in order to delete them. I tried adding this after 'Private Sub formatSave_Click()'

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Also it would be a lot easier to select the content controls by tag instead of by index. I tried this, without success:

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("TaskSteps").Delete
```

"TaskSteps" being the tag name for control (4).

**UPDATE II**

*(Suggestion from stuartd)*

This isn't working to delete hidden text, but maybe I don't have it formatted correctly?

```
Private Sub formatSave_Click()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Hidden = True
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
.Text = ""
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

**SOLUTION:**

Okay I got my original code to work. This is what was happening:

VB deleted ContentControls(4)

I next told it to delete ContentControls(5)

Except that now, with (4) deleted, ContentControls(5) was now ContentControls(4).

So I changed the numbering as shown below, and now it works, and deletes the correct ones:

```
Private Sub formatSave_Click()
'Concept Content = 3
'Task Steps = 4
'ReferenceData = 5

ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True

Select Case strActiveOption
    Case "OptionConcept"
     ActiveDocument.ContentControls(4).Delete
     ActiveDocument.ContentControls(4).Delete
    Case "OptionTask"
     ActiveDocument.ContentControls(3).Delete
     ActiveDocument.ContentControls(4).Delete
    Case "OptionReference"
     ActiveDocument.ContentControls(3).Delete
     ActiveDocument.ContentControls(3).Delete
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Invalid option"
End Select

End Sub
```

I looked at what debug was telling me, stopping on the second deletion in each series, and I finally realized what was going on.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: For each paragraph in active document paragraphs, if is hidden then delete, save as, close without saving changes.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, yeah I've been trying it that way but it's complicated to select the text that's hidden, and it seems to require making it non-hidden, in order to delete it. If you have any pointers about doing this pls let me know.

Comment: Besides telling you the basic concept, no. I'm on mobile right now, so that's difficult anyway. But do add the code you have been trying it with and describe the difficulties you've had with it,  others will find this information useful.

Comment: Tried `wdFormatFilteredHTML` ? Its supposed to strip out the massive bloat/junk that it usually spits out.

Comment: Word's Replace functionality has the option to replace any hidden text with nothing, effectively removing it -     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Hidden = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
     End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Comment: Alex K. Yes, filteredHTML strips out some things but not hidden text.